# CameraX alpha5 bug on target resolution of YUV output?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

```
val imageCaptureConfig = ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().apply {
            setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT)
            setCaptureMode(CaptureMode.MAX_QUALITY)
            setBufferFormat(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
            setTargetResolution(Size(3264, 2448))
            // We request aspect ratio but no resolution to match preview config but letting
            // CameraX optimize for whatever specific resolution best fits requested capture mode
            setTargetAspectRatio(Rational(3,4))
            // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
            // during the lifecycle of this use case
            setTargetRotation(viewFinder.display.rotation)
        }.build()
```

```
imageCapture.takePicture(object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedListener() {
             override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy?, rotationDegrees: Int) {
                        println("captureSuccess h: ${image?.height} w: ${image?.width}")
                    }
             override fun onError(imageCaptureError: ImageCapture.ImageCaptureError, message: String, cause: Throwable?) {
                        println(message)
             }
          })
```

Above is the code I set for capture image from Samsung S8 US version, I want to have YUV format with max output resolution which is 3264*2448. However, the result I got is 1440*1080 instead. I tried on S9, and S8 asian version, the code works fine on both phones. It is strange, when I set the format to JPEG it will work on this phone.

and I tried on S7 and pixel 2 as well, pixel 2 can output YUV at the max supported resolution (not the code above), but S7 cannot, also giving me 1080*1440 instead.

Is this a CameraX bug? If it is, is there any work around besides using back to Camera2?

Thanks!

Comment: as mentioned in camerax documentation, it is still in development stage, either wait until it is fixed or use camera2 api.

Comment: Both S7 and S8 have 12MP rear cameras, 4032*3024; why do you write that max output resolution is 3264*2448?

Comment: @AlexCohn I am using the front facing camera.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the specific devices to verify this, but it's not uncommon that a camera can produce better Jpeg resolution than YUV. On the other hand, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57288661/192373) to a related question.